# How to re render sub component on prop change with redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, immutable.js

I have a react native app using redux and immutable js. When i dispatch an action from my main screen, it goes through my actions, to my reducer and then back to my container, however, the view doesn't update and componentWillReceieveProps is never called. Furthermore, the main screen is a list whose items are sub components **Item**. Here's the relevant code for the issue, if you want to see more let me know.

Render the row with the data:

```
renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
        <Item item={ rowData } likePostEvent={this.props.likePostEvent} user={ this.props.user } removable={ this.props.connected } />
    )
}
```

The part of Item.js which dispatches an action, and shows the result:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.changeStatus.bind(this, "up") }>
                            <Image source={require('../img/up-arrow.png')} style={s.upDownArrow} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={[s.cardText,{fontSize:16,padding:2}]}>
                            { this.props.item.starCount }
                        </Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.changeStatus.bind(this, "down") }>
                            <Image source={require('../img/up-arrow.png')} style={[s.upDownArrow,{transform: [{rotate: '180deg'}]}]} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
```

The action dispatched goes to firebase, which has an onChange handler that dispatches another action.

The reducer:

```
const initialState = Map({
 onlineList: [],
 offlineList: [],
 filteredItems: [],
 connectionChecked: false,
 user: ''
})
...
...
case ITEM_CHANGED:
list = state.get('onlineList')
if(state.get('onlineList').filter((e) => e.id == action.item.id).length > 0){
  let index = state.get('onlineList').findIndex(item => item.id === action.item.id);
  list[index] = action.item
  list = list.sort((a, b) => b.time_posted - a.time_posted)
}
return state.set('onlineList',  list)
            .set('offlineList', list)
```

The container:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
    onlineItems: state.items.get('onlineList'),
    offlineItems: state.items.get('offlineList'),
    filteredItems: state.items.get('filteredItems'),
    connectionChecked: state.items.get('connectionChecked'),
    connected: state.items.get('connected'),
    user: state.login.user
  }
}
```

Where I connect the onChange:

```
export function getInitialState(closure_list) {
  itemsRef.on('child_removed', (snapshot) => {
    closure_list.removeItem(snapshot.val().id)
  })
  itemsRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    closure_list.addItem(snapshot.val())
  })

  itemsRef.on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
    closure_list.itemChanged(snapshot.val())
  })

  connectedRef.on('value', snap => {
    if (snap.val() === true) {
      closure_list.goOnline()
    } else {
      closure_list.goOffline()
    }
  })
  return {
    type: GET_INITIAL_STATE,
    connected: true
  }
}
```

Calling get initial state:

```
this.props.getInitialState({
        addItem: this.props.addItem,
        removeItem: this.props.removeItem,
        goOnline: this.props.goOnline,
        goOffline: this.props.goOffline,
        itemChanged: this.props.itemChanged
    })
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The source of your issue could be with the call to Firebase. If it is an asynchronous call, it's return callback might not be returning something that can be consumed by your action. 
Do you know if it is returning a Promise? If that is the case, middleware exists that handle such calls and stops the calling of an action until a correct response is received. One such middleware is [Redux-Promise](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware).

Comment: So i'm not sure thats the problem because the two actions are seperate. When i press the up arrow it sends an action which changes the database, separately, i have a function connected to an item on change which is supposed to change the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore,combineReducers } from 'redux' //Redux.createStore
import { Provider,connect } from 'react-redux';



//Функція яка змінює store
const hello = (state= {message:'none'}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'HELLO':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {message:"hello world"});
            break
        case  'buy':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {message:"buy"});
            break;
        case 'DELETE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {message:"none"});
            break;
        default :
            return state;
    }
};


const price = (state= {value:0}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'HELLO':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {value: state.value + 1 });
            break;
        default :
            return Object.assign({}, state, {value:0});
    }
};

const myApp = combineReducers({
    hello,price
});

//створюємо  store
let store = createStore(myApp);

let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))



//VIEW
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <p>value: {this.props.price}</p>

                <a href="#" onClick={this.props.onClick}>click</a><b>{this.props.message}</b>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


//mapStateToProps() для чтения состояния и mapDispatchToProps() для передачи события

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        message: state.hello.message,
        price: state.price.value
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
            onClick: () => {

                var items= ['HELLO','buy','DELETE','error']
                var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];

                dispatch({ type: item })
        }
}
}


const ConnectedApp = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(App);




ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedApp />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```